# Как не погрязнуть в проекте с AngularJS и кучей остальных фреймворков?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, framework, архитектура, frontend

Привет! Решил погрузиться в современный мир фронтэнда, попробовал написать приложение и немножко приуныл.

Допустим, я взял за основу AngularJS. В index.html появилось

```
<script src="assets/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
```

Прошла всего пара часов, и вот у меня уже две директивы. Каждую советуют поместить в отдельный js файл:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/image-thumb-full/directive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/shutter-image/directive.js"></script>
```

Кто мы без JQuery?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Захотел [красивый checkbox](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox). Бабах - ещё шесть строчек:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Ну и шрифт же нужно нормальный, чтобы всё Material было

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

А ещё мне понадобится перевод на несколько языков. И ещё какой-нибудь бутстрап. И получается совсем какая-то каша в index.html. Собственно вопрос: **это норма?** Может, есть какие-то приёмы, как организовать это получше? Или это правда нормально, у всех так?

P.S. Структуру проекта брал [отсюдава](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure#a-better-structure-and-foundation). К сожалению, у них нет примера проекта.

Comment: как-то вы не правильно ангуляр используете:) ему не нужен jQuery

Comment: @Grundy о, именно человека с таким мнением я и искал! Можно я покажу вам свою задачу, а вы скажете, можно было обойтись без jQuery или нельзя?

Comment: :-D задавайте вопрос :) этот сайт как раз для этого :)

Comment: @Grundy http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507390/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-angularjs-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если беспокоит количество подключаемых файлов, то используйте [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp). На лету можно собирать все ваши либы, файлы проекта, минифицировать их и соединять в один главный файл, который вы и будете подключать в index.html

Comment: или грунт или любой другой инструмент